# How to filter data in table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 4 options, option 1, option 2, option 3, option 4 and a table.

option 1 = Milk, Eggs, Fish

option 2 = Milk, Eggs, Fish, Shellfish

option 3 = Peanuts, Milk, Eggs, Fish, Shellfish

option 4 = Peanuts, Shellfish, Eggs, Milk, Fish, Tree nuts

What would I need to do to return the results given in the following scenarios:

user selects option 1 and option 2: result is Milk, Eggs, Fish, Shellfish

user selects option 1 and option 3: result is Peanuts, Milk, Eggs, Fish, Shellfish

user selects option 1, option 2, option 4: result is Peanuts, Shellfish, Eggs, Milk, Fish, Tree nuts

and so on, when the user unselects an option.

The idea is that when the user selects or unselects options the result excludes duplicate data.

I don't know if a table is a good format, that could be something else. Data could be static or dynamic.

```js
$(document).on("click", '.filterBtn', function() {

  const filterNumber = $('#filterNumber').val();

  // create a comma seperated list of the class names to show
  var filters = filterNumber.map(function (num) {
    return '.filter_' + num
  }).join()
  
  var trs = $('table tbody tr') // select all the rows

  // if we have filters run the code
  if (filters.length) {
    trs
      .hide() // hide them
      .filter(filters) // find the rows with the class[es]
        .show() // show them
   } else {
     // no filters, just show everything
     trs.show()
   }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="filterNumber">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="filterBtn">Filter</button>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>Milk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>Eggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>Shellfish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>Milk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>Eggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>Fish</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>Shellfish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>Milk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>Eggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>Tree nuts</td>
    </tr> 
     <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>Shellfish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_4">
     <td>Milk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>Eggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_4">
       <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>Tree nuts</td>
    </tr> 
     <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>Peanuts</td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i dont understand your logic, you speak option 1 = ABC and you have just  A to E in your table..would you say option 1 = A or B or C?... and following your logic the option with the biggest index is always the winner?

Comment: option 1 = A and B and C

option 2 = A and B and C and D

option 3 = A and B and C and D and E

option 4 = A and B and C and D and E and F

Comment: user selects option 1 and option 2: result is ABCD
result = ABC + ABCD but we only want to show ABCD
no duplicates in the result

Comment: so following your logic you want to keep always the last filter class?

Comment: you have just changed letter by string.. i dont see how i can understant better what you want .. could you explain why my answer is not ok..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would work http://jsfiddle.net/worldwildweb/qLhuv81r/15/

```js
$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
  var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
  //For each one checked
  $('input:checked').each(function() {
    $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
  });
}).find('input:checkbox').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-
ingredient 1
Alpha isomethylionone
Amyl cinnamal (Jasmonal A)
Amylcinnamyl alcohol
Anisyl alcohol
Benzyl alcohol
Benzyl benzoate


ingredient 2
Benzyl alcohol
Benzyl benzoate
Benzyl cinnamate
Benzyl salicylate
Butylphenyl methylpropional (Lilial)
Cinnamal

ingredient 3
Alpha isomethylionone
Cinnamal
Cinnamyl alcohol
Citral 
Citronellol
Coumarin
-!>
<div class="tags">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="ingredient-1" /> ingredient 1 </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="ingredient-2" /> ingredient 2 </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="ingredient-3" /> ingredient 3 </label>
</div>

<ul class="results">
    <li class="ingredient-1">
        Alpha isomethylionone
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-1">
        Amyl cinnamal (Jasmonal A)
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-1">
        Amylcinnamyl alcohol
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-1">
        Anisyl alcohol
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2">
        Benzyl alcohol
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2">
        Benzyl benzoate
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-2">
        Benzyl cinnamate
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-2">
        Benzyl salicylate
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-2">
       Butylphenyl methylpropional (Lilial)
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-2 ingredient-3">
      Cinnamal
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-3">
        Cinnamyl alcohol
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-3">
        Citral
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-3">
        Citronellol
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-3">
        Coumarin
    </li>
    <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-3">
        Alpha isomethylionone
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your logic: just select the last index of filter:

```js
$(document).on("click", '.filterBtn', function() {

  const filterNumber = $('#filterNumber').val();

  // create a comma seperated list of the class names to show
  var filters = filterNumber.map(function (num) {
    return '.filter_' + num
  }).join()
  
  var trs = $('table tbody tr') // select all the rows

  // if we have filters run the code
  if (filters.length) {
    trs
      .hide() // hide them
      .filter('.filter_' +filterNumber[filterNumber.length - 1]) // find the rows with the class[es]
        .show() // show them
   } else {
     // no filters, just show everything
     trs.show()
   }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="filterNumber">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="filterBtn">Filter</button>


<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_2">
      <td>D</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>E</td>
    </tr> 
     <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>E</td>
    </tr> 
     <tr class="filter_4">
      <td>F</td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: well my question was not clear enough i guess. i will edit it.

Comment: @staflow, dont forget to validate and upvote the answer to close the question. its like that stakoverflow is functional...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set mutiples class in your `TR` tag. Or if you think the number of class could exceed 3-4 class you can use data-*.

So you'll avoid duplicate HTML data as well.

Like :

```
<tr class="filter_1 filter_2">
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr class="filter_3">
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
```

Or with data:

```
<tr data-criteria="filter_1 filter_2">
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
```